# https feed reader. js jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a https site from where I need to create a rss feed. I can successfully get rss feed for http site but I have been unsuccessful for https site. i used google, yahoo and many other for reading rss but have been unsuccessful. I need to read rss feed using jquery or js or jsp/java. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```js
//this is just for test

YUI().use('yql', function(Y){
    var query = 'select * from rss(0,3) where url = "some https site"'
    var q = Y.YQL(query, function(r){
        //r now contains the result of the YQL Query as a JSON
        var feedmarkup = '<p>'
        var feed = r.query.results.item // get feed as array of entries
        for (var i=0; i<feed.length; i++){
            feedmarkup += '<a href="' + feed[i].link + '">'
            feedmarkup += feed[i].title + '</a><br />'
            feedmarkup += feed[i].description + '</p>'
        }
        document.getElementById('qznews').innerHTML = feedmarkup
    })
})
```

```html
//this is just for the test
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.18.1/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
<div id="qznews"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys I was able to solve my above question using this post from stack overflow:https://github.com/sdepold/jquery-rss
Thanks for anyone taking time/effort on my question.

```js
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.3.2/json3.min.js"></script>

  <script src="jquery.rss.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    jQuery(function($) {
      $("#rss-feeds").rss("add any https feed link will work perfectly",
      {
        entryTemplate:'<li><a href="{url}">[{author}@{date}] {title}</a><br/>{teaserImage}{shortBodyPlain}</li>'
      })
    })
  </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  
  
</head>

<body>
  <div id="rss-feeds"></div>
</body>

</html>
```